# AS3 : Only one button pressed down

Tags: actionscript-3

Im using AS3 in multitouch environment.

I got multiple button on a stage, why is it only 1 button at a time can display button pressed down?

All multitouch events seems to be working, the only problem is multiple button pressed down state.

Answer (score 0):

*...why is it only 1 button at a time can display button pressed down?*

No idea. But your best bet would be using MovieClips, just add different states to different keyframes and `gotoAndStop()` when necessary. Or you could be swapping textures or something similar.

Comment: yes, finally i convert all the buttons as MovieClips and trigger Down state on TouchEvent.TOUCH_END.

But with that im using one listeners & function for each button, just to get it to Down state. is there any way to trigger multiple button with one listener and one function?

Comment: Yes, add the listener to the button's parent clip (or stage) and check the event.target in the handler function. If it equals your button(s), trigger its change.